# Angular about.html view not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i created home.html, about.html,app.js,and index.js. i want to show about.html and home.html views in the index.html page. but when i click on the about it shows the home page. the url changes but nothing changes in the browser window.below is the code for app.js

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {


    $routeProvider.when("/home", {
      templateUrl: "home.html",
      controller: "HomeController"
    })
      .when("/about", {
      templateUrl: "about.html",
      controller: "AboutController"
    })
      .otherwise({
      redirectTo: "/home"
    });
  });
  app.controller("HomeController", function($scope) {
    $scope.title = "I'm in home"
  });
  app.controller("AboutController", function($scope) {
    $scope.title = "I'm in about"
  });

}
```

this is the code for the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#/home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div>
        <ng-view>
        </ng-view>
    </div>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

this is code for home.html

```
<div>
{{title}}
</div>
```

this is code for about.html

```
<div>
{{title}}
</div>
```

Comment: put it in js fiddle

Comment: Did you tried ui-router? https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember link format changed from angular 1.6.0.

You may try following link.

```
<li><a href="#!/about">About</a></li>
```

instead of

```
<li><a href="#/about">About</a></li>
```